# Just spent an hour painting a texture and now its turned completely black

Tags: texture-painting

I'm under heavy tension that a texture I've been painting has randomly turned completely black besides its texture icon.
I've already checked my nodes and the image color space is already under 'Srgb' I can't recover any save file as I've just noticed this probably about 1 hour too late. Is there any way to recover the blackened texture?

Comment: Most likely you won't be able to recover the texture. The only thing you'd be able to do is change your workflow moving forward so that problems like this are greatly minimized. One thing you can do is `File > Save Copy` to create backup points for yourself to go back to

Comment: To further elaborate on the above comment by Gunt.r, images edited and/or painted within Blender are not saved as part of your file when you hit ctrl-s. You need so save them out as separate files (I believe it's alt-s or you can use the top menu bar in the image editor).